# Flutter: Bottom Navigation Bar Cutting off Label Text

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I have a `BottomNavigationBar` where everything is working properly except it is cutting off the text on the 'Notifications' label. It appears to cut the label text at 13 characters. No matter how small I make the font with `selectedFontSize` of where I put the lab in the nav bar, it still cuts it off and gives 'Notificati...'. Is there a way to fix this? See image below for the result from the code.

```
const Map<int, String> tabName = {
  0: 'Feed',
  1: 'Challenges',
  2: '',
  3: 'Invite',
  4: 'Notifications',
};

Map<int, Widget> tabIcon = {
  0: Icon(
    Icons.home_outlined,
    size: 32.sp,
  ),
  1: Padding(
    padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 4, bottom: 4),
    child: FaIcon(
      FontAwesomeIcons.trophy,
      size: 23.sp,
    ),
  ),
  2: Icon(
    Icons.add_box_outlined,
    size: 35.sp,
  ),
  3: Icon(
    Icons.person_add,
    size: 30.sp,
  ),
  4: Icon(
    Icons.notifications_active,
    size: 30.sp,
  ),
};

Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BottomNavigationBar(
      backgroundColor: Color(0xFF1E1E24),
      selectedItemColor: FlutterFlowTheme.primaryColor,
      unselectedItemColor: Colors.white,
      showSelectedLabels: true,
      showUnselectedLabels: true,
      type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed,
      selectedFontSize: ,
      items: [
        _buildItem(tabItem: 0),
        _buildItem(tabItem: 1),
        _buildItem(tabItem: 2),
        _buildItem(tabItem: 3),
        _buildItem(tabItem: 4),
      ],
      onTap: (index) => onSelectTab(index),
      currentIndex: currentTab,
      // selectedItemColor: AppColors.addEntryColor!,
    );
  }

BottomNavigationBarItem _buildItem({int tabItem}) {
    return BottomNavigationBarItem(
      icon: _tabSelected(tabItem),
      label: tabName[tabItem],
    );
  }

  Widget _tabSelected(item) {
    if (item == 4) {
      return getNotificationIconWithBadge();
    } else {
      return tabIcon[item];
    }
  }
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

`TextOverflow.Ellipsis` is the acting agent here which works when the width of the label increases the available width, which is based on the number of items of the `BottomNavigationBar`. To force the label to be visible completely irrespective of the available width, you can use `TextOverflow.visible` as:

```
 return BottomNavigationBar(
      ...
      //Setting it to visible will make the label text visible completely
      selectedLabelStyle: const TextStyle(overflow: TextOverflow.visible),
      unselectedLabelStyle: const TextStyle(overflow: TextOverflow.visible),
    );
```

In your example:

```
 return BottomNavigationBar(
      backgroundColor: Color(0xFF1E1E24),
      selectedItemColor: FlutterFlowTheme.primaryColor,
      unselectedItemColor: Colors.white,
      showSelectedLabels: true,
      showUnselectedLabels: true,
      type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed,
      selectedFontSize: ,
      items: [
        _buildItem(tabItem: 0),
        _buildItem(tabItem: 1),
        _buildItem(tabItem: 2),
        _buildItem(tabItem: 3),
        _buildItem(tabItem: 4),
      ],
      onTap: (index) => onSelectTab(index),
      currentIndex: currentTab,
      // selectedItemColor: AppColors.addEntryColor!,
      selectedLabelStyle: const TextStyle(overflow: TextOverflow.visible),
      unselectedLabelStyle: const TextStyle(overflow: TextOverflow.visible),
    );
```

But, point to remember is if there's not enough width and you force the label to be shown completely, it will break in multiple lines as in the image below:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, that did show the rest of the text. However, like you mentioned, it is just now going to the next line. I am guessing each of the `BottomNavigationBarItem` is wrapped in a column that is not allowing it grow horizontally no matter how small the text is. Any ideas?

Comment: As your usage is a simple BottomNav without Fab, you can create your a custom one with Row, 5 Expanded with `flex:1` and Column as Child, it's super easy.